# Issue with mirrored uv seam from blender to unreal

Tags: uv, mirror, seams

[image: MIRRORED UV LAYOUT]I have cut half of the model and made UV layout and then mirrored the model in blender. The UVs of mirrored model are overlapped and then I baked the normal map. My issue is when I exported this model to unreal engine I am able to see the seem where I have mirrored.
[image: when exported to unreal engine]  How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Hi! Could you please give more context to this question? editing and adding screenshots can be a huge help at diagnosing the issue and will help you get a better answer faster! As is there isn't really any way we can help you :)

Comment: Hello and welcome. As it stands this question is unanswerable and was put on hold for lack of essential details to understand the issue. Risking stating the obvious, only you have access to your scene, so unless you describe it thoroughly you alone know your exact setup, settings and what steps you took to arrive where your are now. Describe the issue in detail, add [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) of relevant settings and user interface, with the [edit] button above. Don't post comments or ask a new question, editing will automatically queue it for reopening review.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 standard formats of normal maps, DirectX and OpenGL. Both have the same capability, only their green channel (RGB map) is inverted to each another.

[image]

Here you can see which software uses formats of normal maps:

| Software | DirectX | OpenGL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3DS Max | ✓ |  |
| Arnold |  | ✓ |
| Blender |  | ✓ |
| Cinema 4D |  | ✓ |
| Corona | ✓ |  |
| CryEngine | ✓ |  |
| Houdini |  | ✓ |
| Marmoset Toolbag |  | ✓ |
| Maya |  | ✓ |
| Octane |  | ✓ |
| Redshift |  | ✓ |
| Substance Painter | ✓ |  |
| Unity |  | ✓ |
| Unreal Engine | ✓ |  |
| VRay |  | ✓ |
| Zbrush |  | ✓ |

As you see, Unreal and Blender uses different formats, so that you have to convert it. In order to convert from one system to another, just invert Green channel in 2D editor like Photoshop or Gimp